# Как писать вывод в С1 ЕГЭ по русскому языку?

Tags: грамотная-речь, егэ

При написании сочинения, я использую различные клише, которые сам и придумал. 
Эксперт объяснила мне, что у меня неправильно написан вывод в моих сочинениях. 
Пример:

> Из всего вышесказанного можно сделать вывод о том, что данная проблема актуальна и популярна, ведь она рассматривается во многих литературных произведениях разного времени.

Или ещё:

> В заключении можно сделать вывод о том, что данная проблема актуальна в современном мире.

И ещё:

> Из всего вышесказанного я сделал вывод о том, что проблема эгоизма, поднятая Чеховым актуальна и рассмотрена во многих классических художественных произведениях разных времен.

Выше Вы прочитали выводы в моих сочинениях. **Они все неправильные.**

Скажите, пожалуйста, как писать вывод и есть ли клише?

Большая просьба, Уважаемые форумчане, пишите только те, кто знает как писать для ЕГЭ и разбирается в этом, так как модель написания, как у меня, навязана мне школьным учителем, хотя педагог хороший.

Comment: ВладиславМСК? О каком заключении Вы рассуждаете? Надеюсь, не о том, куда помещают людей, опасных для общества. (Нужно  писать: *в заключение*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ВладиславМСК, вывод, в соответствии с кольцевой композицией, должен возвращать к сути проблемы, а не к заключению о её актуальности. Например: *Таким образом, настоящий друг действительно тот, на кого можно положиться в самый трудный момент.*

1. Порассуждав вместе с автором о проблеме эгоизма, мы приходим к выводу: эгоизм становится...
2. Таким образом,эгоизм действительно...
3. Так размышления по тексту привели нас к мысли о том, что...
4. Итак, мы доказали, что...

Как видите, вывод — это  идея Вашего текста, короткий ответ на проблему представленного текста.